# Unable to write to a script tag in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, nullpointerexception, servercontrols

I have a script that I want only to load if a certain condition was met, so I figured I should do this:

```
//Head tag
<script type="text/javascript" id="scriptArea" runat="server"></script>
//Rest of the page
```

.cs (Page_Load event)

```
if(someCondition)
{
    scriptArea.InnerHtml = "Javascript code";
}
```

The problem is I get a null pointer exception and when it stops, I discover that scriptArea is `null` for some reason. Why does this happen and do you know of another solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using asp.net webforms and script `runat="server"` ends up being server executed code, see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f0111sbh.aspx) on documentation about this.

If you just want javascript, try this instead:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    <asp:literal id="scriptArea" runat="server" />
</script>
```

Then in your code behind

```
scriptArea.Text = "Javascript code";
```